# Trim Canvas to First Visible Pixel

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, transparency, crop, canvas

I have a large amount of 1024x1024 images that are mostly transparent pixels. I need to crop these images to the smallest possible centered square that includes all pixels. In other words: I need to trim the canvas equally, on all sides, until I run into a non-transparent pixel.

Example 1:

The 1024x1024 image is completely transparent, except for one black pixel located at 1003, 1011. The resulting image is 1011x1011.

Example 2:

The 1024x1024 image is completely transparent, except for a 100x200 black rectangle in the dead center. The resulting image is 200x200.

Photoshop's "trim" command seems a step in the right direction, but most options I've found trim *everything* to visible pixels which makes me lose the centerpoint reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with Gimp: the [`ofn-centered-autocrop` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/). Autocrops this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: +1 I just knew somewhere there'd be an easy, automated, method.

Comment: @Scott There wasn't (to my knowledge) until a couple of hours ago :)

Comment: Ahh.. okay.. good on you `:)` I'd upvote again if I could.

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop, you could record an action to automate this.

Open the *Actions* panel, press *Create new set*, name it and press *OK*. Then press *Create new action*, name that too and press *Record* to start recording.

First we make a merged duplicate of the document.

- Perform *Select > All Layers*.
- Perform *Edit > Copy Merged*.
- Perform *Edit > Paste Special > Paste in Place*.

We then rotate the duplicate 90 degrees and make two additional duplicates which we rotate to 180 and 270 degrees.

- Perform *Select > All*.
- Perform *Edit > Transform > Rotate 90° Clockwise*.
- Perform *Layer > Duplicate Layer*. Press *OK*.
- Perform *Select > All*.
- Perform *Edit > Transform > Rotate 90° Clockwise*.
- Perform *Layer > Duplicate Layer*. Press *OK*.
- Perform *Select > All*.
- Perform *Edit > Transform > Rotate 90° Clockwise*.

Now we can trim the document and clean up.

- Perform *Image > Trim*. Select *Based on > Transparent Pixels*, make sure all the *Trim Away* boxes are ticked and press *OK*.
- Perform *Layer > Delete > Layers*.
- Perform *Layer > Delete > Layers*.
- Perform *Layer > Delete > Layers*.
- Perform *Select > Deselect*.

End the recording by pressing *Stop playing/recording* in the *Actions* panel.

[image]

Comment: cant you copy and rotate multiple layers?

Comment: @joojaa, no ... you're right, it was too destructive. I've changed the method so it makes a merged duplicate instead of merging the layers.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly.... you want to crop **proportionally** to the first pixel **any** edge would hit. Essentially move the outer image boundaries *inward* until any side hits a pixel.

You can do this manually in Photoshop provided *snapping* is on.

[image]

- Grab the **Crop Tool**
- Click-drag a corner near where the pixel is located.
- Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys 
  <sub>(Option/Alt moves the crop from *center*, Shift keeps the crop *proportional*.)</sub>
- Drag inward

You should see the crop box *snap* when it gets close to the pixel.

[image]

Let go and commit the crop.

---

I'd wager this *could* be automated, possibly in a script. And I have an inkling that software such as ImageMagik would automate this as well. But that's not my strong point. Perhaps someone will have an "automated" answer.